# Vulnerability examples using eval() plug-ins in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, eval

I have inherited a WordPress website that uses the RunPHP plug-in for executing snippets of PHP code in between posts. I have a feeling that this isn't the best way to implement such functionality. But since this is legacy code that has been functionally correct for a very long time, I'll need some solid examples of problem scenarios.

For those not familiar with RunPHP, it is a plug-in which executes PHP code embedded inside the Post or Page body using eval(). The code block is never received from the user, but entered into the database by the site owner / content creator.

The use case for this plug-in in our context is as follows.

A form is created as a Post, whose submit action is set to a Page (let's call it form handler). The form handler contains PHP code in its body and the RunPHP plug-in is activated for that Page. When the form gets submitted, the form handler receives the data and the PHP code in its body is executed.

This is besides some rather glaring security issues in the form handler code (dynamic user-submitted variable evaluation, no input-sanitization, no parametrized SQL queries).

Can somebody here verify my doubts about runtime code execution plug-ins in WP?

Much appreciated.

Form code in a Post -

```
<form action="/?p=1234" method="post">
    <input name="foobar" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Handler code in a Page (this is stored in the database, and eval()-ed at runtime) -

```
<?php
    $foobar = $_POST["foobar"]; // This contains a SQL-injection vulnerability; But that's a separate issue, I think
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES (\"" . $foobar . "\")"; // Use variable in a query string
?>
```

Comment: Hard to judge without seeing some actual code I think

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think code might be a bit irrelevant. All I'm asking is whether anybody can think of security vulnerabilities using eval() on trusted code containing user-submitted variables in PHP.

Comment: I might have sounded a bit rude above, so I've added some sample code to illustrate my point. Let me know if this helps clarify my point a bit.

Comment: Too broad. `eval` as the sole security pitfall is a dated generalization. It entirely depends on how it is used, e.g. if in admin settings or actual user-supplied content, which your description and examplarized code doesn't reveal.

Comment: I've further refined the code example to show what is done with the user-submitted value. In most cases, it is strung together into a string to be used as a query.

Comment: The example handler code is prone to sql injections ...but regardless of whether it's executed by eval() or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without seeing the actual site/code, but generally eval is a potential gateway for security problems. Imagine your site has an SQL injection problem somewhere: attackers have the possibility to not only inject data but also working PHP code into your application. Eval has some (few) valid areas of use, but in general I'd avoid it. Wordpress is quite easy to extend, maybe try porting the functionality to plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Who submits these forms? If it can be submitted by anyone and everyone, what prevents them from executing code to fetch whatever interests them?

You can use this exploit to potentially read files, execute MySQL queries, etc.